# Trying to Monitor a Windows Server using Nagios over WAN

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2008, nagios

I am running Nagios from my LAN on a VM running Ubuntu Server. I am trying to monitor a Windows server located and via the Internet. I set up a public IP in my NAT which forwards to my Nagios server as needed.

I cannot seem to be able to ping the Nagios server from the Windows server, nor can I reach the Windows server from the Nagios server (can only ping the Windows server if I disable the public profile in the Windows Firewall).

I'm not sure where/how to proceed. I read that ports 5666-5667, 1248-1249 and 12489 need to be forwarded, but I do not know if that would be on the Nagios server, Windows Server or all of the above.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to monitor?  **There is a wide variety of methods and protocols** that Nagios can use to monitor a Windows system (wmi, winrm, nsclient++ push or pull, and more).  Which method you use defines which ports you need to open and permit through the firewall.

Comment: I'm trying to monitor CLIENTVERSION, UPTIME, CPULOAD, MEMUSE, USEDDISKSPACE, MySQL57, TOMCAT7 and APACHE2.4 (Last 3 appear as services).

Comment: Most likely you want your Nagios server to poll the Windows server (probably NSClient++ on port 12489).  If that's the the case then probably you need to be looking at the firewall on the Windows side to allow your nagios server to reach tcp 12489 and udp 8 for basic ping checks on the Windows server.  It sounds like you focused on the firewall at the nagios side first and possibly unnecessarily.